# How to nest slash command subcommand groups in Discord.JS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js

For example, I want to have a command with this structure:

`/command subcommandgroup subcommandgroup subcommand`

In this example, the tree describing the relationship between subcommands are as follows:

```
command
|- subcommandgroup1
|   |- subcommandgroup1_1
|   |   |- subcommand1_1_1
|   |   |- subcommand1_1_2
|   |- subcommandgroup1_2
|   |   |- subcommand1_2_1
|   |   |- subcommand1_2_2
|- subcommandgroup2
|   |- subcommandgroup2_1
|   |   |- subcommand2_1_1
|   |   |- subcommand2_1_2
|   |- subcommandgroup2_2
|   |   |- subcommand2_2_1
|   |   |- subcommand2_2_2
```

Unfortunately, Discord's API, therefore also Discord.JS, only can do as much as the following:

`/command subcommandgroup subcommand`

TL:DR; I want to have more than one level of subcommand groups under a given command.

**What is a good workaround for this limitation?**

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be useful to let the user choose the action using the `String` option and `choices`.

Examples: `/command subcommandgroup1 subcommand1 action:someaction`

```json
{
  "name": "command",
  "description": "Command",
  "options": [{
    "type": 2,
    "name": "subcommandgroup1",
    "description": "subcommandgroup1",
    "options": [{
      "type": 1,
      "name": "subcommand1",
      "description": "subcommand1",
      "options": [{
        "type": 3,
        "name": "action",
        "description": "choose action",
        "required": true,
        "choices": [ { "name": "Action 1", "value": "action1" } ]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this comes with some drawbacks when further nesting. Adding another action as a choice where that action requires completely different options compared to the other actions won't be possible. In other words, this would not extend further when more "subcommands" are nested.

Comment: I think it is somewhat possible to use `autocomplete` in action2 (although `autocomplete` cannot restrict input like `choices`, so validation is needed on the bot side there).